# Cannot acccess folder with admin rights on windows

Tags: windows, permissions

I am having issues with folder permissions on Windows 10 x64. For whatever reason, my folder permissions keep requiring 'admin privileges to access certain folders. When I grant admin privileges, I get a permission denied message. How can I be denied access to these folders even with admin privileges?

Also how do recursively grant security rights to the current user to a folder via powershell?

Comment: Did you check the Owner?

Comment: I have admin privileges....

Comment: I had similar issue and running icacls PATH /reset /t /q on problematic folder (documents in my case) reset permission to default and I could continue working. Wasted quite a lot of time on taking ownership messing around in advanced security with usual solutions. This solved my issue in 5 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following powershell to reset the permissions on the users or administrator.

According to `Venkatakrishnan`'s answer in the link: [Setting NTFS Permissions With Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40336969/setting-ntfs-permissions-with-powershell)

```
$Folderpath='Destination Folder'
$user_account='User Acccount'
$Acl = Get-Acl $Folderpath
$Ar = New-Object system.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($user_account, "FullControl", "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
$Acl.Setaccessrule($Ar)
Set-Acl $Folderpath $Acl
```

Hope it can help you.